Structure code to avoid borrow checker punishment
I am trying to structure pretty simple stuff, in fact to DRY up some code and extracted it into a separate method. Borrow checker does not allow me to do that. Is there a best practice to make something like this?
Borrow checker does not allow me to run the following code:

cannot borrow *self as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Neither I can make it mutable, because borrow checker also is not happy about it.
It means the normal boilerplate refactoring approach does not work in rust, can't just split method to two method and reuse some code.
pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: Option<String>,
    pub baz: String,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn first(&mut self) {
        match self.bar {
            None => {}
            Some(ref mut v) => {
                self.second(v);
                println!("{}", v);
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn second(&self, s: &mut String) {
        s.push_str(&self.baz);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {
        bar: Some(String::from("hello")),
        baz: String::from("world"),
    };
    foo.first();
}


At first look I would use associated method which looks like a pair of crutches, perhaps there is anything else?

Its a bit hard to understand the needs by code block with no explanation. What is the goal you're looking for? From what are you refactoring?

I want to split one function to two functions and call second from the first (and third and so on). For some reason borrow checker does not allow that. It's basically "extract method" approach.

Can you provide a piece of code that can reproduce the issue? If I'll use the code added, would the error appears?

Of course it will appear. What a point of posting working code to introduce a problem?

It's a chance you already have an Option for the .bar member.
You can simply take the string from the option, leaving None instead, then reassign it afterwards.
    pub fn first(&mut self) {
        match self.bar.take() {
            None => {}
            Some(mut v) => {
                self.second(&mut v);
                println!("{}", v);
                self.bar = Some(v);
            }
        }
    }

In the initial version, calling .second() was an attempt to mutate .bar (as v) while the whole struct containing .bar was also supposed to be referenced.
In the modified version, the compiler is now certain that mutating v in .second() will not interfere with the structure as a whole.

It does not matter to take or not to take, rust does not allow me to borrow self as immutable within mutable fun. I have updated the question.

Thanks, works for my case. But I guess there must be some general purpose approach to address complex problems.


Handle None.
Shrink function size and simplify.
Avoid side effect — avoid mut when possible.
Pass by reference, try not to take, to_owned and so on, avoid state management.
Avoid unnecessary clone.
As long as str can be known at compile time, no need to put extra effort for having String, it's more expensive to move around and does not implement Copy when you need to work around borrow.

pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: Option<String>,
    pub baz: String,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn first(&self) {
        if let Some(v) = &self.bar {
            self.second(v);
            println!("{}", v);
        } else {
            println!("bar is None");
        }
    }

    pub fn second(&self, v: &str) {
        let result = format!("{}{}", v, self.baz);
        println!("{}", result);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        bar: Some(String::from("hello")),
        baz: String::from("world"),
    };
    foo.first();
}

For the immutable borrow in mut fn, true, but you can borrow immutably the fields:
impl Foo {
    pub fn first(&mut self) {
        match self.bar.as_mut() {
            None => {}
            Some(v) => {
                Foo::second(&self.baz, v);   
                println!("{}", v); 
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn second(baz: &String, s: &mut String) {
        s.push_str(baz);
    }
}

